# ExecuteScalar throws NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This code throws a `NullReferenceException` when it calls `ExecuteScalar`:

```
selectedPassengerID = 0;

//SqlCommand command = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();


// 2nd test
string connectionString = "";
SqlConnection conn;

connectionString = ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["ConnST-MHM"].ConnectionString;
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandText = "SearchForPassenger";

SqlParameter param;

param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = pName; // Session[""];
param.DbType = DbType.String;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@flightDate";
param.Value = date; 
param.DbType = DbType.String;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ticketNo";
param.Value = ticketNumber; 
param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

int item;

command.Connection.Open();
item = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have encapsulated most of my SQL logic in a DAL.  One of these DAL methods pulls scalar Ints using the following logic.  It may work for you:

```
  object temp = cmnd.ExecuteScalar();
  if ((temp == null) || (temp == DBNull.Value)) return -1;
  return (int)temp;
```

I know that you have entered a lot of code above but I think that this is really the essence of your problem.  Good luck!

Comment: checking for DBNull is critical since it will help you a lot if you can to nulluable types. +1

Answer (score 7):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns null if no records were returned by the query (eg when your `SearchForPassenger` stored procedure returns no rows).

So this line:

```
item = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Is trying to cast `null` to an `int` in that case. That'll raise a `NullReferenceException`.

As per [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559632/executescalar-gives-nullreferenceexception/559660#559660) that just poppped up, you need to check for `null`:

```
object o = command.ExecuteScalar();
item = o == null ? 0 : (int)o;
```

Comment: thanks ,
Why null ? 
I checked that in ssms and it worked ,
please help

Comment: What does your stored proc return, given the same parameters that your program calls it with?