# How to recognize empty result from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

When my select command does not have any result, it throws an exception. Instead I want to continue with the process without exception. How to control this by checking whether there is data retrieved from the select statement?

Here is my query:

```
sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Front_end = '" + strfrontend + "'ORDER BY Date_time desc", con);
id = sqlid.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: You know that your code is not SQL injection safe

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: why dont u accept the answer?

Comment: I'm necroing this because people have pointed out that this is vulnerable to SQL Injection, but no one told the OP how to prevent it.

Here's a good explanation of how to use parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection. https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Answer (score 4):

Using exceptions to control program flow (as suggested by other answers) is the [wrong solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729404/453277). If its acceptable to return no results, check the value returned from `ExecuteScalar()` before calling `ToString()` on it.

By [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), ExecuteScalar will return null if there are no results.

```
object val = sqlid.ExecuteScalar();
if( val != null ){
    id = val.ToString();
}else{
    // do something (or nothing) and continue
}
```

See also: [ExecuteScalar throws NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559632/executescalar-throws-nullreferenceexception)

Comment: hi tim, thanks for you explanation and the link to the other question, never thought to check the if the value was null... i guess that solves the problem as well.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the down vote was deserved as it was bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteScalar and handle empty result this way:

```
SqlCommand sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Front_end = '" + strfrontend + "'ORDER BY Date_time desc", con);

SqlDataReader dr = sqlid.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
 id  = dr[0].ToString();
}
else
{
    // handle empty result here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice?

```
 SqlDataReader rd = cmdLoad4.ExecuteReader();
 if (rd.HasRows)
{
// input what you want.
}
else
{
//input the exception
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Would a try-catch block not work?

```
    try
    {
        //Execute your SQL-statement here        
    }
    catch(SqlException)
    {
        //If you want something specific to happen when the
        //exception is thrown, put that here.
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: -1 using exceptions to control program flow is poor practice, especially when the exception is so easy to prevent.

Answer (score -1):

encapsulate it with a try/catch statement :

```
try
{
    sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Proj_id FROM Proj_details 
                           WHERE Front_end = '" + strfrontend 
                           + "'ORDER BY Date_time desc", con
                           ); 
    id = sqlid.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch(exception)
{
   // do something with the exception
}
```

Comment: -1 using exceptions to control program flow is poor practice, especially when the exception is so easy to prevent.